# Docker compose gradle plugin exits with "docker inspect" requires at least 1 argument

Tags: java, macos, docker, gradle, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:0.9.6
    ports:
      - "4576:4576"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs:4576
      - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localhost
      - DEBUG=0
      - START_WEB=0

  primarydb:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: test-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test-password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test-password
    ports:
      - "3318:3306"
```

And I have the following gradle configuration:

```
    apply plugin: 'docker-compose'
    dockerCompose.isRequiredBy(project.tasks.getByName('test'))

    dockerCompose {
        useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose.yml']
        startedServices = ['localstack', 'primarydb']

        projectName = "${rootProject.name}"
    }

    project.tasks.getByName('test').doFirst {
        systemProperty 'localstack.sqs.endpoint', "http://localhost:4576"
        systemProperty 'mysql.url', "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3318"
    }
```

And I am using the latest docker-compose plugin: `com.avast.gradle:gradle-docker-compose-plugin:0.15.1`

For some reason, the build works on my friend's Linux machine, but it doesn't work on MacOS 11.4.
When I run `./gradlew composeUp` task it just fails with the following error message:

```
./gradlew composeUp      

> Configure project :
2.5.25-SNAPSHOT

> Task :composeUp
Container primarydb-1  Running
Container localstack-1  Recreate
Container localstack-1  Recreated
Container localstack-1  Starting
Container localstack-1  Started
"docker inspect" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker inspect --help'.

Usage:  docker inspect [OPTIONS] NAME|ID [NAME|ID...]

Return low-level information on Docker objects

> Task :composeUp FAILED
...
```

Any idea why this plugin doesn't work on a mac but works on my friend's machine?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. Running `./gradle composeUp --stacktrace` gave a clue what `com.avast.gradle:gradle-docker-compose-plugin:0.15.1` is doing. In essence to does:

1. `docker-compose -p <project name> up`
2. `docker-compose -p <project name> config --services` and finally
3. `docker-compose -p <project name> ps --services`

The third a last step is the one which was failing on me (and is the one currently failing on you.) Repeating the compose-commands manually and having a look into the Docker Desktop UI I could see, that docker-compose did alter my project-name by removing any dots from it. After respecifying

```
dockerCompose {
    [...]
    projectName = 'name-without-dots'
}
```

thus ensuring that docker-compose wont alter the project name, did solve the issue for me.

Your error cause migth still be a different one. Try running `./gradlew composeUp` with `--stacktrace`, `--info` or even `--debug` to get a better understanding of what is going wrong.